# ServiceStack AutoQuery not working for DateTime values

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a ServiceStack service using autoquery where the DateTime greater than or less than are being ignored.

Here is my request DTO:

```
    public class GetSources : QueryBase<DbSource, Source>
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string NameContains { get; set; }
       public string NameStartsWith { get; set; }
       public DateTime? LastUpdatedDateGreaterThan { get; set; }
       public DateTime? LastUpdatedDateLessThan { get; set; }
    }
```

The database table poco generated from the ormlite T4 template looks like this:

```
[Alias("DbSources")]
[Schema("SomeSchema")]
public partial class DbSource 
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public DateTime LastUpdatedDate { get; set;}
}
```

In the service I do some validation and then use AutoQuery like this:

```
    var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(dto, Request.GetRequestParams());
    q.Join<DbSource, CompanySource>((source, companySource) => source.Id == companySource.SourceId && companySource.CompanyID == companyId);
    return AutoQuery.Execute(dto, q);
```

I'm using mstest

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetSources_LastUpdatedGreaterThan()
    {
        var expected = DateTime.Now;
        var query = new GetSources { LastUpdatedDateGreaterThan = expected};
        QueryResponse<Source> result;
        using (var service = appHost.Container.Resolve<SourceService>())
        {
            service.Request = new MockHttpRequest();
            result = service.Any(query);
        }
        log.Info(result.ToJson());
        result.Results.ForEach(src => Assert.IsTrue(src.LastUpdatedDate > expected));
    }
```

Name, NameContains, and NameStartsWith all work as expected in other tests, but both LastUpdatedDateGreaterThan and LastUpdatedDateLessThan do not generate a where clause. In my AutoQuery setup all of the properties are defaults except for EnableUntypedQueries which is false.

I know I can explicitly add the where for them in the service. i.e.

```
    q.Where(source => source.LastUpdatedDate > dto.LastUpdatedDateGreaterThan);
```

But if possible I would like AutoQuery to take care of it.  Does DateTime work with AutoQuery? Or am I doing something wrong in my code.

Comment: Can you put together a stand-alone repro (e.g. in a github repo or gist), as I'm not able to repro [any issues using DateTime with AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/90153dde65475f7fd81bca73766524b50e36d68b).

Answer (score 1):

I ran through the Servicestack AutoQuery unit tests that mythz created using sql server. I tested using a database view which my original project was querying against and I wasn't able to replicate the issue I'm having. For now I'm going to just add the QueryField attribute to the DateTime properties on the Query model like this:

```
[QueryField(Template = "{Field} > {Value}", Field = "LastUpdatedDate")]
public DateTime? LastUpdatedDateGreaterThan { get; set; }
```

Adding the attribute gives me what I need.  I'll spend some time tracking down the culprit in my code later.